# Returning entity on ajax call

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, security

Is there any problem (security, consistency, bad practice etc) on returning the entity instead of a VO or DTO on Response of ajax call?

Small example:

**JAVA:**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "loadSomething.do")
public @ResponseBody RealEntity loadSomething(){
    return service.getRealEntity();
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST', 
    url: rquestURL, 
    cache: false,
    success: function(realEntity) {
        doSomething(realEntity);
     }});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem in returning the entity. The purposes of a VO are different than those specified in this question.

https://dzone.com/articles/value-objects